# I don't know how to fix this

Tags: java

I have this assignment I have to do.. and I don't know how to fix the problem so that my program will work.

```
import  java.util.Scanner;
public class Work6{

   public static void main (String[] args){
       String x;
        String y;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number 1:  ");
        x = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Number 2: ");
        y = in.nextLine();

     if (x > y){
            System.out.println("Bigger number: " + x);

        }
        else if (y > x){
            System.out.println("Bigger number: " + y);
        }
    }

}
```

Basically I have to write a program that asks for two numbers and then tells me which one is bigger. Can you just please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks, Eva

Comment: you compare `String`'s, while you should be comparing `int` here.

Comment: Do `int x; int y` instead of `String x; String y;` and instead of `in.nextLine()` do `Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine())`.

Comment: I actually see that the code won't even compile with a respective error message.

Comment: Please use a better title than "I don't know how to fix this", e.g. "Problem determining bigger of two numbers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change x and y to int:

```
import  java.util.Scanner;
public class Work6{

   public static void main (String[] args){
    int x;
    int y;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Number 1:  ");
    x = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Number 2: ");
    y = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();

 if (x > y){
        System.out.println("Bigger number: " + x);`

    }
    else if (y > x){
        System.out.println("Bigger number: " + y);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are scanning strings and then you compare its memory locations, to see which one is larger...

What you need to do is, to scan numbers not strings, and it will work:

```
import  java.util.Scanner;
public class Work6{

   public static void main (String[] args){
   int x;
    int y;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Number 1:  ");
    x = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Number 2: ");
    y = in.nextInt();

 if (x > y){
        System.out.println("Bigger number: " + x);`

    }
    else if (y > x){
        System.out.println("Bigger number: " + y);
    }
}

}
```

You should read more about primitives and objects and how to compare them.

**EDIT**

It can also be shorter:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        int x;
        Integer y;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number 1:  ");
        x = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number 2: ");
        y = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(x > y ? "Bigger number: " + x : 
              x == y ? "They are equal" : "Bigger number: " + y);
        }
```

**EDIT 2:**

You can still use strings if you want, but you need to create Integer out of it:

```
        String x;
        String y;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number 1:  ");
        x = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Number 2: ");
        y = in.nextLine();
        int xInt = new Integer(x);
        int yInt = new Integer(y);
        System.out.println(xInt > yInt ? "Bigger number: " + x : x == y ? "They are equal" : "Bigger number: " + y);
```

What this code does, it reads lines and then you try to create Integer from it. If its not a valid Integer, Exception will be thrown here, so be careful with this. Also, its unboxed to int, I would recommend you to read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `in.nextInt()` instead of `in.nextLine()`. It will return an `int` instead of a string!